# Qt - Finding a printer

Tags: c++, qt, printing, file-permissions

I need to find if a printer has a given model.

I found QPrinterInfo - that has a property printerName

Unfortunately, when adding a printer in Linux the user can make up the name however he wants, or change it after install, so the name would not be reliable

I read that Qt 5.x has a "printerModel" and that would be great... but I have to use 4.7-8

I tried to read from /etc/cups/printers.conf

```
QString fileName = "/etc/cups/printers.conf";
QFile printerConf(fileName);
if (printerConf.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    // i wish but it never happens
}
```

But I can't read it because of permissions.

Qt 4.8, Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cups API has all the information needed:

http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/api-cups.html

```
#include <cups/cups.h>

cups_dest_t *dests;
int num_dests = cupsGetDests(&dests);
cups_dest_t *dest;
int i;
const char *value;

for (i = num_dests, dest = dests; i > 0; i --, dest ++)
  if (dest->instance == NULL)
  {
    value = cupsGetOption("printer-make-and-model", dest->num_options, dest->options);
    printf("%s (%s)\n", dest->name, value ? value : "unknown");
  }

cupsFreeDests(num_dests, dests);
```